# User-specify link function with two to-be-estimated parameters (ex-gaussian) for glm in R

Tags: r, glm, lme4

I am trying to define a link function with ex-Gaussian for glm family. There are three parameters to be estimated from the ex-Gaussian function. And I'm interested in two of them: mu and tau. (The mu is the mean of the normal (gaussian) part of the data and the tau is the mean of the exponential part of the data.) I checked the documents for other link function and found usually there is only one parameter (mu) to be estimated. I wonder if it is possible to self define a link function with ex-Gaussian (two parameters) for glm family? If yes, how should I set the link function for two parameters?

I would like to use ex-gaussian to estimate both the mu and tau from the response time (RT) distribution. I understand log transformation is available for RT. But here I'm particularly interested in the two components of the RT distributions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This seems like a statistics question, not a programming question, so it should go on stats.stackexchange, not here.

Comment: Not going to pretend to be an expert here, but generally a GLM is given by `g(mu) = X * beta`. Seems like you're asking for `g(mu, tau) = (X * beta_mu, X * beta_tau)`, sort of simultaneously (?) estimating 2 linear models. Maybe it's two GLMs, or maybe it's something else, but it certainly doesn't seem like a very simple extension of GLM. I'd suggest looking up examples/articles of fitting ex gaussian distributions and doing something well-established rather than hacking your own.

Comment: Thanks. Recently I found it may be useful to use Bayesian mixed modeling (e.g., brms), which can estimate multiple parameters.